# How to explode data from other website

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my code but not working while exploding but on another link like `http://www.pricetree.com/mobile/86` is working right

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.snapdeal.com/products/mobiles-mobile-phones/filters/Form_s~Smartphones?sort=plrty');
```

we need perticular data from page not entire page. echo $homepage

```
$product_list = explode('<div class="col-xs-6  product-tuple-listing js-tuple ">', $homepage);
```

please help me anyone to explode data from other website

Comment: Are you familiar with **Web Scrapping** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = explode ( '<div id="snapdeal_price">', $price );
    $price = explode ( '</div>', $price [1] );
    echo $price = $price [0];
```

try this ...... change div your want